# .NET Rx Koans: Why does this test case fail?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, system.reactive

While looking for material to learn Rx, I found this: [Reactive Extensions (Rx) Koans](http://rxkoans.codeplex.com/). From the intro:

> **Definition of ‘Koan’**
>   Kōans is a zen word meaning the enlightenment or awakening of a person, usually through a puzzle or riddle. The most common one is “What is the sound of one hand clapping?”

It is composed of many short test cases that teach different aspects of Rx.

One of them should intuitively pass, however, it fails. Can you explain why ?

Here it is, in full:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Timeout(___)] //"Fill in the blanks" - I tried several values, e.g. 4000. No changes.
    public void AsynchronousRunInParallel()
    {
        Func<int, int> inc = (int x) =>
                                {
                                    // I set a breakpoint here and it's never hit.

                                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                                    return x + 1;
                                };
        double result = 0;
        var incAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, int>(inc.BeginInvoke,
                                                             inc.EndInvoke);
        incAsync(1).Merge(incAsync(9)).Sum()
                               .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Immediate)
                               .Subscribe(n => result = n);

        Assert.AreEqual(12, result);
                    //the failing message says: 'expected 12, got 0'
    }
```

Comment: Did you add the thread sleep? If so, that's the cause - you're checking the result before the actual operations have had time to finish.

Comment: The only thing I edited was the "fill in the blanks" part.

Comment: The way I understand it: `Merge` "spills" the results from two "pipes" (two `IObservable`'s) into a single pipe, as they come; `Sum` subscribes to an `IObservable` and consumes *all* its elements (and sums them), then returns a new IObservable with a single element (the sum) which is then consumed by `Subscribe( n=> ...)` . The `Scheduler` part is a black box for me, for now.

Comment: I tried removing the `Thread.Sleep()` and indeed, the test passes. But I still don't understand why. What I expected from this test (looking at the "fill in the blanks" part) was to see that long operations are parallelized (e.g. set the time limit for the test to 2 seconds (enough for two runs of `inc` in parallel, but not enough if they run serially), and see it pass).

Comment: Which VS/testrunner are you using?

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu What I was going to reply with was too long for a comment, so I added an answer. :)

Comment: @nemesv VS2012 (Express) / MS test

Comment: @JerKimball ...and it got accepted, too! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

you're not allowing enough time for the asynchronous portion of the test to execute before checking the results.

Longer answer:

The sequence of actions this test performs is a bit like:

- Set up an `IObservable` that will asynchronously invoke a delegate
- Chain that into another `IObservable` that is the merged results of two of those asynchronous calls, summed together
- `Subscribe` to the resulting `IObservable`, causing two async invocations of the method
- Doh! there is a `Thread.Sleep` in the delegate, so the asynchronous invocation is blocked!
- Immediately check the result, which of course will be 0 - the two blocked async calls haven't "finished"

There are a number of ways you can "fix" this:

- remove the `Thread.Sleep`
- Change the call to be synchronous by changing `BeginInvoke`, although this would require a whole restructuring of the test
- Use a `HistoricalScheduler` instead of the `Immediate` one

Using a `HistoricalScheduler` is HIGHLY recommended while trying to unit test Rx stuff - basically, it lets you jump forward and backward in virtual time, a key feature for testing time-dependent code like Rx queries:

```
var theTardis = new HistoricalScheduler();

Func<int, int> inc = (int x) =>
{
    theTardis.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));
    return x + 1;
};
double result = 0;
var incAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, int>(inc.BeginInvoke,inc.EndInvoke);

incAsync(1).Merge(incAsync(9)).Sum()
    .SubscribeOn(theTardis)
    .Subscribe(n => result = n);

// To the FUTURE!
theTardis.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Assert.AreEqual(12, result);
```

Comment: `theTardis` made me giggle :). Nice piece of information! I fixed it differently: before the assert, I make sure the pipeline is complete by `WaitOne()` on an `AutoResetEvent`; the event is `Set` in the `Action<>` passed to the end of the chain: `Subscribe(n => {res = n; evt.Set();})`. Is there a cleaner (Rx-ier) way to wait on the IObservable ?

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu The `HistoricalScheduler`, really - or what you just did by manually waiting on a `WaitHandle`

Comment: The best way to do something after an Observable sequence finishes is not to wait, but to add more to the end of Observable (ie. `LastOrDefaultAsync().Do()`). Or even to `await`, if you're in an async method. If you must have it block, though, there is the `Wait()` extension method.

Comment: @Cory I can't seem to find any documentation to `LastOrDefaultAsync()` (link pls?); and, although I can guess what this does (and am aware of the pass-through nature of `Do()` ), I'm not sure how I would plug it in the existing chain of calls. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what a synchronous version looks like - the most direct version of what you've got. `Single()` will block until the observable completes. Blocking is usually something you want to avoid, but if you're just messing around it's fine.

```
public void AsynchronousRunInParallel()
{
    Func<int, int> inc = (int x) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        return x + 1;
    };

    var incAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, int>(inc.BeginInvoke,
                                                         inc.EndInvoke);

    int sum = incAsync(1).Merge(incAsync(9)).Sum().Single();

    Assert.AreEqual(12, sum);
}
```

And an asynchronous TPL version, using `await`:

```
public async Task AsynchronousRunInParallel()
{
    Func<int, int> inc = (int x) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        return x + 1;
    };

    var incAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, int>(inc.BeginInvoke,
                                                         inc.EndInvoke);

    int sum = await incAsync(1).Merge(incAsync(9)).Sum();

    Assert.AreEqual(12, sum);
}
```

And finally an asynchronous one which uses Rx `Do()` -- good if say this was part of a bigger operation:

```
public async Task AsynchronousRunInParallel()
{
    Func<int, int> inc = (int x) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        return x + 1;
    };

    var incAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<int, int>(inc.BeginInvoke,
                                                         inc.EndInvoke);

    await incAsync(1).Merge(incAsync(9)).Sum().Do(sum =>
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(12, sum);
    });
}
```

Comment: Using the await dramatically simplified my tests. I was fearing having to do polling or the AutoEvent above. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that it is a bug in source code and AsynchronousRunInParallel is missing result awaiting which is used for example in TheBloodyHardAsyncInvokationPatter.

When FromAsyncPattern is used, only BeginInvoke is executed in the current thread synchronously. The actual work and result handling will be scheduled on ThreadPool. Thus, execution of Assert will be started as soon as 2 async increments are scheduled, without any wait for completion.

I've added:

```
ThreadUtils.WaitUntil(() => result != 0.0);
```

so the result looks like:

```
        incAsync(1).Merge(incAsync(9)).
            Sum().SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Immediate).
            Subscribe(n => result = n);
        ThreadUtils.WaitUntil(() => result != 0.0);
        Assert.AreEqual(12, result);
```

Or you may want to replace "Subscribe" with "Run". It is a helper method from Koan itself, which will wait using a manual event:

```
incAsync(1).Merge(incAsync(9)).
             Sum().SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Immediate).
             Run(n => result = n);
Assert.AreEqual(12, result);
```